# How does apps like Whatsapp or telegram listen to the incoming call/message events on Android?

Tags: background, android-service, xmpp, sip, android-8.0-oreo

I built a VoIP calling app which maintains a persistent connection with the server to listen to any incoming calls. I implemented a background service to do this.

But since Oreo, this running code is now broken because of the introduction of [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html)

After looking into forums, I found that some people are suggesting

1. **Convert Service to JobService and let android schedule it**

   Doing so, my app won't be able to receive calls when it is stopped
2. **Run your operations in foreground services**

   It is annoying for some users to see a constant notification in the notification bar. So these above-mentioned options aren't working for me to fix my code for Oreo.

How does WhatsApp get the incoming (VOIP) call in Android (Oreo onwards) working around the [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html)?

Comment: Great SO, today I am seeking the right solution as well. What's the best way to solve this issue!

Comment: You can use firebase push notifications to inform your app that some info (text, call) is coming and then your app can start a short-lived service to capture the info. That is one way I found. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming that you are using SIP to establish the connection and initiate calls. Without a service constantly re-sending REGISTERs, the app doesn't receive INVITEs when the server sends them.

A workaround for this problem is what is called the "push notification strategy". It works as follows, when the server sends a INVITE, it also sends an FCM notification to your app, This wakes up your app which then sends a REGISTER to your server, which in return forks the call to your app. [Here is a video that better explains this strategy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XIrR9bwUkM&t=)

Comment: However whatsapp probably has their own protocol for starting a session, as they only need to support whatsapp to whatsapp calls, and they control both endpoints.

Comment: Now that Android has introduced so many restrictions, I guess it is the only way. Anyway whatever protocol whatsapp may use, they will also have to deal with these restrictions.

Comment: @Kantajit you are correct, Whatsapp probably also uses some form of notification, however, it is possible that Whatsapp's protocol allows for all the information to start the session to be in the notification, so that the receiver's app only needs to respond to the notification, this is unlike SIP, where you need REGISTERs, and INVITEs.

P.S. The Android (&iOS pre iOS 13) restrictions are good IMO, Keeping a SIP client running in the background can really drain a battery

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

- use platform push services (APNS or FCM)
- maintain persistent socket connection and exclude application from battery optimisations.

Comment: thanks, wojtek.  
But I think excluding application from battery optimizations takes care of the doze mode. That was introduced in Android 6.0 (API 23).
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

My problem is avoiding background execution restrictions which were introduced in Android O.

Answer (score 3):

(Sticky) **foreground** services are not affected by the restrictions. So you could use one those as replacement for background services on Oreo.

But foreground services have two disadvantages: They are less likely killed by the system in order to reclaim resources compared to background services, and hence affects the Android system's self-healing capability. And they require you to display a permanent notification. But Users are able to suppress the notification, somewhat mitigating this disadvantage.

Comment: how does whatsapp then listens to INCOMING_CALL (non VoIP) without using READ_PHONE_STATE runtime permission??